# MSBuild project deploy to local folder with config transformed

Tags: deployment, msbuild

I'm having trouble trying to find the right way to use MSBuild to build a web project and output the project with only deployable files (i.e. no .cs, .csproj, .Debug.config etc.), but published to a local folder that I can then FTP, RoboCopy, (or whatever) to a secondary location.

The published output must have the Web.config file pre-transformed as per the specified configuration and the transformation config files (e.g. Web.Debug.config) *not* included in the output. I don't need any fancy publishing to IIS, database deployment or anything like that, I just want clean file system output that I can then test. Note that this cannot be done using visual tools as I want to run it as part of an automated build process.

I can generate a web deployment package, but I can't get WebDeploy to work because it doesn't seem to handle quoted command line options anymore (seems to be some kind of bug) and the directory structure has spaces, so I was hoping to accomplish the whole task using MSBuild, seeing as MSBuild seems to have native capacity to transform the config file (`TransformXml`), which is the only real bit of proper deployment functionality I'd be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it figured out eventually. The following build script does the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll"/>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputDir>obj\website-output</OutputDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="PrepareDeploy">
        <ItemGroup>
            <DeployableFiles Include="App_Code/**/*.*;App_Data/**/*.*;Areas/**/Views/**/*.*;bin/**/*.*;Views/**/*.*;*.aspx;*.asax;*.html;*.htm;sitemap.xml;*.ico;*.png" Exclude="App_Data/**/*.log" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <RemoveDir ContinueOnError="true" Directories="$(OutputDir)" />
        <MSBuild Projects="Website.csproj" />
        <MakeDir ContinueOnError="true" Directories="$(OutputDir)" />
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(DeployableFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(DeployableFiles->'$(OutputDir)\%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
        <TransformXml Source="Web.config" Transform="Web.$(Configuration).config" Destination="$(OutputDir)\web.config" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```